# Get Properties of Adobe Flex Charts

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I need to get all the properties of flex charts by using/calling the respective chart.
Example For Flex Area Chart we have xField,yField and minField.

Is there any way to get these properties from each chart through any methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods on the charts that will do this. If you want to find out the properties of the chart and their series, you will need to do this via reflection.

You can use the global describeType() method on any object for this. This will return you an XML object containing all properties of the object.

There is also an API on top of describeType that allows for easier access and introspection of objects: [AS3Commons Reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be useful, is an example for view all information of the **ChartBase** object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.charts.chartClasses.ChartBase;

            public function init():void{
                getInfo(new ChartBase());   
            }

            private function getInfo(obj:Object):void{
                txt1.text = describeType(obj);
                var myXML:XMLList = new XMLList(describeType(obj));
                var info:String = "";
                for each(var node:XML in myXML.children()){
                    switch(node.name().toString())
                    {
                        case "variable":
                        {
                            info = info + "var - " +  node.@name + "\n";    //properties
                            break;
                        }
                        case "accessor":
                        {
                            info = info + "accessor - " +  node.@name + "\n";   //getter-setter
                            break;
                        }
                        case "method":
                        {
                            info = info + "method - " +  node.@name + "\n"; //methods
                            break;
                        }                               
                    }
                    txt2.text = info;
                }

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Label text="View Information of 'ChartBase' Object"/>
    <mx:HBox width="100%">
        <mx:HBox width="50%">
            <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Label text="All Object Information"/>
                <mx:TextArea id="txt1" width="800" height="800"/>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox width="50%">
            <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Label text="Properties,Accessor and Methods from this Object"/>
                <mx:TextArea id="txt2" width="800" height="800"/>   
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:HBox>      
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Basically the method `describeType` returns a XML with the object information.

- [Adobe reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html)
- [Performing object introspection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7fe8.html)

Here you can run a SWF with this code **[LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExObjectInfo.swf)**.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.

Comment: @user2677772: You're welcome. Could solve the problem with the information that I posted?